# Trabajar con todos los campos que devuelve una tabla PHP, JQUERY,MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Buenas, tengo un problema que es que necesito manipular todos los registros que hay de una tabla,es decir, estoy creando una inbox, con bandeja de entrada y las tablas y la parte del backend están bien, me devuelve todos los mensajes que me escribieron, ya que todos los mensajes que me escriban valga la redundancia, se almacena en la tabla y si son para mi usuario registrado me los devuelve la tabla, y a su vez yo mostrarlos en pantalla el problema esta, en que como los mensajes provienen de distintos usuarios por ejemplo, necesito acceder a cada uno de ellos, esto se como hacerlo luego, pasando parámetros, el problema esta en que la tabla los datos que me devuelve solo puedo manipular un campo!!! es decir, es como un bug que solo puedo tocar el primer registro y los demás están como muertos sin eventos, ni nada y la idea es poder trabajarlos todos para así ver que usuario me envía un mensaje, aca anexo mi código

```html
<?php
                            require_once 'wp-admin/history.php';
                            $data_message = new  history();
             $inbox = $data_message->inbox($_SESSION["id"],$_SESSION["nick"]);
                            if($inbox!=0){
                                $inbox_message = TRUE;
                            }else{
                                $inbox_message = FALSE;
                            }
                            if($inbox_message){                                
                                foreach($inbox as $key):
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                        <img class="media-object img-circle"                                          src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30/people/1/" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                    <div id="data_imbox" class="media-body">
                                        <h4 class="media-heading">Jane Smith
                               <span class="small  pullright">12:23PM</span>
                                        </h4>
      <p>Hi, I wanted to make sure you got the latest product report. Did Roddy get it to you?</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>                                              
                           <?php endforeach;} ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-footer">
                        <script>
                        jQuery("#data_imbox").click(function(){
                           alert("hello word"); // PARA testear, solo funciona con el primer registro que devuelve la tabla, es decir si la tabla hay 7 registros el primero que me devuelve es el que puedo manipular los otros 6 solo aparecen en mi div, pero como muertos, el DOM no lo he modificado con php para mostrar los mensajes de distintos usuarios
                        });
                        </script>
                    </div>
```

Cabe destacar que tambien lo intente hacer todo con php puro, y sigue el mismo problema, los eventos, todo lo que asigne se lo da al primer registro los demás están como muertos, solo aparecen porque los devuelve la tabla

Comment: A. No se comprende bien cuando dices _los demás están como muertos_ ... B. ¿Estás llamando todo lo que necesitas en el ´SELECT ...´? C. ¿Puedes mostrar cómo consultas a la base de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas,

Dado tu codigo:

```
jQuery("#data_imbox").click(function(){
    alert("hello word");
});
```

Claramente solo funcionará con un solo elemento, ya que el listener se lo estas dando al ID Element `#data_imbox`, pero resulta que todos tus elementos tienen el mismo identificador y justamente la gracia del ID es que no puede haber otro elemento con el mismo ID.

Mi recomendación es que le des al listener el atributo class quedando de esta manera.

```
jQuery(".media-body").click(function(){
    alert("hello word");
});
```

Espero te pueda servir este ejemplo.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @jolsalazar, por el simple hecho de olvidar esa teoría me costo un mundo algo tan sencillo